# Getting my table privileges for Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

There is a list of tables in a Oracle Database that I want to test if I have privileges particularly to read data. I only know of;

```
select * from all_tables
```

where it returns tables that I have, but there are instances where the data is not made available to me.

Rather than looping through a list of tables, and `select` each table, is there a quick way for this?

I am not an admin and would prefer a quick method for this rather than going back and forth with the DBA everytime.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "here are instances where the data is not made available to me"?

Comment: @SamM where I can view them in `all_tables` but I do not have select privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you got it wrong.

`ALL_TABLES` shows - as its name suggests - **all** tables you have access to, not (as you said, tables that you have - those are contained in `USER_TABLES`).

Here's a quick test:

```
SQL> connect mike/lion@orcl
Connected.
SQL> select count(*) from all_tables;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       111

SQL> select table_name from all_tables where owner = 'SCOTT';

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
BONUS

SQL> connect scott/tiger@orcl
Connected.
SQL> grant select on emp to mike;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect mike/lion@orcl
Connected.
SQL> select count(*) from all_tables;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       112

SQL> select table_name from all_tables where owner = 'SCOTT';

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
EMP
BONUS

SQL>
```

The `SELECT` privilege is what you're interested in ("... particularly to read data"), so - here it goes: once you're granted the privilege, that table *appears* in `ALL_TABLES`. No need to bug the DBA.

---

**[EDIT]**

A table can be listed in ALL_TABLES, but you don't have privileges to select from it. Here's an example:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger@orcl
Connected.
SQL> revoke select on emp from mike;

Revoke succeeded.

SQL> grant insert on dept to mike;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect mike/lion@orcl
Connected.
SQL> select count(*) from all_tables;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       112

SQL> select table_name from all_tables where owner = 'SCOTT';

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
DEPT
BONUS

SQL> select * from scott.dept;
select * from scott.dept
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


SQL>
```

To check privileges you have, run

```
SQL> select table_name, privilege from all_tab_privs where grantor = 'SCOTT';

TABLE_NAME                     PRIVILEGE
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
BONUS                          UPDATE
BONUS                          SELECT
BONUS                          INSERT
BONUS                          DELETE
DEPT                           INSERT      --> see? Only INSERT on DEPT

SQL>
```

Comment: am I understanding it wrong that I might see the table in `all_tables` but unable to run a `select` clause on it?

Comment: A table can be listed in ALL_TABLES, but you can't select from it. I edited my message and added some more code which illustrates that. Have a look, please.

Comment: Understood, I am not able to view any `PRIVS` tables and that is what is limiting me at the moment, looks like the only ways are for me to `select` from all tables from my list or get the DBA to extract from `all_tab_privs`

Comment: As far as I can tell, you don't need any additional privileges to see ALL_ views. You can't query **DBA**_TAB_PRIVS (unless you're allowed to), but **ALL**_ ... it just should be available to you. Check with your DBA, maybe - for some reason - your privileges were revoked ...